# Spring MVC display SOAP message in HTML using Model

Tags: xml, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, soap

I am building a small monitoring program and I want the user to be able to see what the system in actually sending. So I have a small SOAP message such as

Unfortunately, I am not able to display it at all in the JSP using

${channel.payload}

I have tried different approach using CDATA but with no success so far.

Does anyone have a good idea on this ?

Comment: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">
     <soap:Body xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
          <m:GetStockPrice>
               <m:StockName>IBM</m:StockName>
          </m:GetStockPrice>
     </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: The previous is an example of a typical soap message sent by the system.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the html tag textarea work fine.

EX.

```
<textarea>${channel.payload}<textarea>
```